# Combinatorics- distribute n objects to k bin with constraints

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose I have n objects distributed to k bins and I want to know how many multisets satisfy the following condition: exactly j bins have at least m objects, where j $\leq$ k,m $\leq$ n, and j*m $\leq$ n. For example, if n = 5, k=4, j=2 and m = 2, there are 24 subsets:

[3, 2, 0, 0]
[3, 0, 2, 0]
[3, 0, 0, 2]
[2, 3, 0, 0]
[2, 2, 1, 0]
[2, 2, 0, 1]
[2, 1, 2, 0]
[2, 1, 0, 2]
[2, 0, 3, 0]
[2, 0, 2, 1]
[2, 0, 1, 2]
[2, 0, 0, 3]
[1, 2, 2, 0]
[1, 2, 0, 2]
[1, 0, 2, 2]
[0, 3, 2, 0]
[0, 3, 0, 2]
[0, 2, 3, 0]
[0, 2, 2, 1]
[0, 2, 1, 2]
[0, 2, 0, 3]
[0, 1, 2, 2]
[0, 0, 3, 2]
[0, 0, 2, 3]

I'm having difficulty finding a general formula for this problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose which of the $j$ bins have at least $m$ objects in $\binom{k}j$ ways. Let $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_j$ be number of objects minus $j$ in these $j$ bins. Let $y_1,y_2,\dots,y_{k-j}$ be the number of object in the other bins. Then
$$
\begin{align}
x_1+\dots+x_j+y_1+\dots+y_{k-j}&=n-jm,\\
0 &\le x_i,\\
0&\le y_i<m
\end{align}
$$
If we ignored the condition $y_i<m$, then we would have several non negative integers summing to $n-jm$; the number of ways to do this is $\binom{n-jm+k-1}{k-1}$, using stars and bars. In order to account for $y_i<m$, we use inclusion exclusion. Namely, subtract out the bad solutions where $y_i\ge m$ for each $i$, then add back in the doubly subtracted solutions where $y_i\ge m$ and $y_j\ge m$, then subtract out the triply bad solutions, etc. The result is
$$
\binom{k}j\sum_{\ell = 0}^{k-j}\binom{k-j}{\ell}(-1)^\ell \binom{n-(j+\ell)m+k-1}{k-1}
$$
Here, I am using the convention that $\binom{n}k=0$ when $n<k$.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I believe I identified a case where it fails: n=4,k=3,m=4,j=1. I think it should equal ${k \choose j}$ = 3. I suspect the inclusion-exclusion method might be failing because something is overcounted in certain cases.

Comment: If you apply my formula in your comment, you should get $$\binom{3}1\left(\binom{2}0\binom{2}2-\binom{2}1\binom{-2}{2}+\binom{2}2\binom{-6}2\right)=3(1-0+0)=3,$$ which is correct.

Comment: You are right. Sorry for the confusion. The [program](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/math/#Base.binomial) I am using yielded ${-2 \choose 1}$ = -2, which was unexpected.  Thanks again!

Comment: The confusion is my fault. Most mathematicians agree that $\binom{-2}1=-2$; it just makes my formula more convenient to write if you assume $\binom{-2}1=0$.